# nativescript: white bar on bottom of splash screen regardless of fixing constraints

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I used NativeScript Sidekick to build my splash screen.  I have the white bar at the bottom of the splash screen on iPhone X and above.  I tried to follow this guide: https://blog.angelengineering.com/nativescript-splashscreen-iphonex/ to adjust the constraints however every time I run `tns run ios` to relaunch the app in the ios simulator, I see the changes in xCode revert and the white bar shows again.

Comment: Did you copy the updated launch screen to app resources / iOS? Anything you find in platforms folder is auto generated and could be overwritten on every build.

Comment: that was it, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything you find in `platforms` folder is auto generated and could be overwritten on every build.

You may use the auto generated one as a template, modify the launch screen from platforms folder then copy it back to `App_Resources/iOS`.